# How to make everything on a web page unclickable until something loads with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I've made my own anti-adblock program for my website with Javascript. There is a slight delay before the actual alert comes up, and during that time, users have the ability to click anything on my actual webpage.

Is there something I can add to my Javascript that makes the rest of my webpage unclickable unless no adblock is detected?

I'm aware what I can add to my CSS to make the page unclickable, but I'm not sure how I can make that *only* active if I detect an adblocker.

Comment: Did you consider just prevent the default click event?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click listener to the window, in the capturing phase, and call `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault` on the event, so that other listeners don't run:

```js
const handler = e => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
};
window.addEventListener('click', handler, true);
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('clicks enabled');
  window.removeEventListener('click', handler, true);
}, 3000);

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => console.log('button 1 clicked'));
```

```html
<button>click to run listener attached via JS</button>

<button onclick="console.log('button 2 clicked')">alert</button>

<form>
<button>submit form</button>
</form>
```